# How to mend specific records in a live SQL Azure instance? Best Practice?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to work out the best practice for recovering specific records that get corrupted in a live SQL Azure DB.

I have got the automatic BacPac reports working.

Currently I would import the relevant BacPac into a recovery DB instance and then compare this instance with the live instance using MS SQL Data Tools or Red Gate Data Compare, and then create a sync script for the required records. Not sure if this is the best practice approach though.

This is also part of a slightly bigger question which is how to do deal with certain backup situations ie

1) Complete DB corruption

> > Recover using complete BacPac

2) Significant number of records damaged

> > difficult to answer!!

3) Small number of corrupt records to mend, using user specific records.

> > Use Data compare tools such as MS SQL Data Tools or RedGate Data Compare.

A colleague also mentioned to me about "periodic transaction log backups". Not sure if SQL Azure does these?

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.